# How to get the belongsTo model without making new db requests in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Gallery.php:

```
<?php

class Gallery extends Eloquent {

    protected $visible = array(
        'title',
        'slug',
        'id'
    );

    public function coverImage() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Image', 'cover_image_id');
    }

}
```

Image.php:

```
<?php

class Image extends Eloquent {

    protected $visible = array(
        'id',
        'url'
    );
    protected $appends = array(
        'url'
    );

    public function gallery() {
        return $this->hasOne('Gallery', 'cover_image_id');
    }

    public function getUrlAttribute() {
        $slug = $this->gallery->slug;
        return '/images/' . $slug . '/' . $slug . '-' . $this->id . '.jpg';
    }

}
```

What I want is:

```
return Response::json(Gallery::all()->with('coverImage')->get());
```

And I want every `coverImage` to have `url` attribute. It has... but Laravel is querying the datebase for every gallery to get its `slug` although it has galleries because of the `with()` method.

How to avoid it?

Comment: Just a thought, but shouldn't one of the classes Gallery or Image have a hasOne relation to the other, instead of the both of them having a belongTo?

Comment: @Adimeus You're right. I've edited my question. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. I've "select * from `galleries` where `galleries`.`cover_image_id` = ? limit 1" for each `gallery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how Eloquent relations work. They are **not bidirectional**. So:

```
$model = Model::with('related')->first(); // loads related on model

$model->related; // eager loaded

// but
$model->related->model; // not eager loaded, so requires query
```

Last line is true even though `$model` and `->model` refers to the same row in DB.

That being said, you need to eager load `gallery` on the images:

```
return Response::json(Gallery::with('coverImage.gallery')->get());
```

Comment: Ok, this is much better but it produces two identical queries. Is this the best and only way to achieve what I need?

Comment: this is the easiest possible solution that requires only a few letters of code. If you're worried about performance then use join instead.